# Modifying get_author_posts_url() in Multisite

Tags: multisite, author

I'm not sure if this is a known WordPress Multisite bug, or the way the Multisite I am working on was setup. The kind of issue I am having is similar to [this one](http://www.feedmeastraycat.net/2011/10/04/wp-get_author_posts_url-in-mu-with-sub-directories/).

The links created by `get_author_posts_url()` in the theme's `functions.php` file, to generate the link for the author, end up having an extra "`/blog`" in front of them and they should not. Within the child sites, the `get_author_posts_url()` generated links are all OK and do not contain the "`/blog`" in the URL string.

Here is the [website](http://blogs.slq.qld.gov.au/). When you click on an author link from the featured post tiles, you get an error 404 page returned. If you go into on of the child blogs - it does not happen.

How can I remove "`/blog`" from the link string data generated by `get_author_posts_url()`?

For more info, please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623040/modifying-get-author-posts-url-in-wordpress-multisite) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: hurrah, this post got 'tumbleweed' status! Can close this off as I solved the issue by using a .htaccess redirect rule.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've resolved it using .htaccess, but this is generally something you can amend in the site settings in your Network admin. Go to Sites, click Edit, and then scroll down to find the permalink structure which probably look like this: /blog/%posttitle%.

Just remove the '/blog' part, click save and you'll probably find it's ok.

I did read somewhere that re-saving your permalinks over-rides this settings so you need to go back into the site via network admin to remove /blog again.

Hope that helps!